Extra Space below Navigation Bar in Android
Image Shows Extra Space
I am experiencing an issue with extra space appearing below the BottomNavigationView on all devices. In my layout, I have a ConstraintLayout that contains a Toolbar at the top and a BottomNavigationView at the bottom. Despite setting constraints to align the BottomNavigationView to the bottom of the parent layout, there is still a significant gap below it on all devices. I have tried removing padding and margin attributes, setting a fixed height for the BottomNavigationView, and ensuring proper constraints, but the issue persists. Below is the XML code for my layout. Any suggestions on how to eliminate this extra space and ensure the BottomNavigationView aligns properly at the bottom of the screen would be greatly appreciated.
XMl file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nexa_regular"
                android:text="Refine"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/refineBtn"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/refine_btn"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/location"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nexa_regular"
                android:text="Howdy!!"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Extension"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="11dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/menu"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Please help to Resolve this problem. It will be very helpful

I was also encountering the same problem, to solve this issue just replace the value systemBars.bottom with 0 in the onCreate() function of the java file of the activity containing bottom navigation bar , it worked for me.
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
        Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
        v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right,systemBars.bottom);
        return insets;
    });
}

